# How to convert GML/JSON to RDF?

Tags: geolocation, rdf, opendata

i've got a geo-related dataset with coordinates and want to convert it into RDF to publish it as Linked Data. The dataset exists in the formats GML, KML, JSON, CSV and XSD. The content is just about points with a description.

I'm just a beginner in this area, so i would like to ask you, which possibilities do i have to convert it to RDF? I found already a collection of Converters on http://www.w3.org/wiki/ConverterToRdf and  http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/RDFizers but the needed formats are not supported. I tried to use an XML converter for the GML file to see whats happens, but the result only contains meta data information.
Besides this i tried the TopBraid Composer testversion, but after installing i'm not sure of how to use it resp. i haven't found the JSON2RDF function somewhere.

Do you have any ideas or approaches of how i can convert the dataset? I'm searching for an as-simply-as-possible solution, that other beginners can repeat this work quickly.

Attached some extract from the JSON File. The whole dataset in various formats can be found here:
https://geo.sv.rostock.de/download/opendata/naturdenkmale/

```
JSON:
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "bezeichnung": "1. Stieleichen mit Hecke", "bezeichnung_latein": "Quercus robur et. al.", "veroeffentlichung": "BeschluÃŸ Rat d. Stadt 94\/51\/81 18.06.1981" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.061458855408354, 54.141761469057052 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "bezeichnung": "2. Stieleichen mit Hecke", "bezeichnung_latein": "Quercus robur et. al.", "veroeffentlichung": "BeschluÃŸ Rat d. Stadt 94\/51\/81 18.06.1981" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.061222607125485, 54.141793579585588 ] } },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing for you to do is probably just write something quick and dirty to do the transformation.

[Sesame](http://openrdf.org) has a pretty nice API called RIO for doing RDF reading & writing, so if you're working with Java, that's imo your best option.

Grab any off the shelf JSON parser and you can do a pretty simple conversion into triples and stream them to a RIO RDF writer to output them in the format of your choice.  You can pick a schema of your own for naming the predicates, classes, etc, or you can probably grab something off schema.org to reuse.